Not able to access GPIO pins on my Raspberry Pi 5
I recently got started with device drivers programming on my Raspberry Pi. I was writting a program to access GPIO pins. I'm facing an error during gpio_request(). Cant seem to figure out what the problem is, can someone please help and tell me where im going wrong.
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/gpio.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Johannes 4 GNU/Linux");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A simple gpio driver for setting a LED and reading a button");

static dev_t my_device_nr;
static struct class *my_class;
static struct cdev my_device;

#define DRIVER_NAME "my_gpio_driver"
#define DRIVER_CLASS "MyModuleClass"

static ssize_t driver_read(struct file *File, char *user_buffer, size_t count, loff_t *offs)
{
    int to_copy, not_copied, delta;
    char tmp[3] = " \n";
    to_copy = min(count, sizeof(tmp));
    printk("Value of button: %d\n", gpio_get_value(17));
    tmp[0] = gpio_get_value(17) + '0';
    not_copied = copy_to_user(user_buffer, &tmp, to_copy);
    delta = to_copy - not_copied;
    return delta;
}

static ssize_t driver_write(struct file *File, const char *user_buffer, size_t count, loff_t *offs)
{
    int to_copy, not_copied, delta;
    char value;
    to_copy = min(count, sizeof(value));
    not_copied = copy_from_user(&value, user_buffer, to_copy);
    switch (value) {
        case '0':
            gpio_set_value(4, 0);
            break;
        case '1':
            gpio_set_value(4, 1);
            break;
        default:
            printk("Invalid Input!\n");
            break;
    }
    delta = to_copy - not_copied;

    return delta;
}

static int driver_open(struct inode *device_file, struct file *instance)
{
    printk("dev_nr - open was called!\n");
    return 0;
}

static int driver_close(struct inode *device_file, struct file *instance)
{
    printk("dev_nr - close was called!\n");
    return 0;
}

static struct file_operations fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = driver_open,
    .release = driver_close,
    .read = driver_read,
    .write = driver_write
};

static int __init ModuleInit(void)
{
    printk("Hello, Kernel!\n");

    if (alloc_chrdev_region(&my_device_nr, 0, 1, DRIVER_NAME) < 0) {
        printk("Device Nr. could not be allocated!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printk("read_write - Device Nr. Major: %d, Minor: %d was registered!\n", my_device_nr >> 20, my_device_nr && 0xfffff);

    if ((my_class = class_create(DRIVER_CLASS)) == NULL) {
        printk("Device class can not be created!\n");
        goto ClassError;
    }

    if (device_create(my_class, NULL, my_device_nr, NULL, DRIVER_NAME) == NULL) {
        printk("Can not create device file!\n");
        goto FileError;
    }

    cdev_init(&my_device, &fops);

    if (cdev_add(&my_device, my_device_nr, 1) == -1) {
        printk("Registering of device to kernel failed!\n");
        goto AddError;
    }

    /* GPIO 4 init */
    int ret;
    ret = gpio_request(4, "led_gpio");
    if (ret) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Failed to request GPIO pin\n");
        return ret;
    }

    /* Set GPIO 4 direction */
    ret = gpio_direction_output(4, 0);
    if (ret) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Failed to set GPIO pin direction\n");
        gpio_free(4);
        return ret;
    }

    /* GPIO 17 init */
    if (gpio_request(17, "rpi-gpio-17")) {
        printk("Can not allocate GPIO 17\n");
        goto Gpio4Error;
    }

    /* Set GPIO 17 direction */
    if (gpio_direction_input(17)) {
        printk("Can not set GPIO 17 to input!\n");
        goto Gpio17Error;
    }

    return 0;
Gpio17Error:
    gpio_free(17);
Gpio4Error:
    gpio_free(4);
AddError:
    device_destroy(my_class, my_device_nr);
FileError:
    class_destroy(my_class);
ClassError:
    unregister_chrdev_region(my_device_nr, 1);
    return -1;
}

static void __exit ModuleExit(void) {
    gpio_set_value(4, 0);
    gpio_free(17);
    gpio_free(4);
    cdev_del(&my_device);
    device_destroy(my_class, my_device_nr);
    class_destroy(my_class);
    unregister_chrdev_region(my_device_nr, 1);
    printk("Goodbye, Kernel\n");
}

module_init(ModuleInit);
module_exit(ModuleExit);

The kernel message prints out the error handling message for the gpio_request() in the code when I try to install the module onto the board. Tried with different pin numbers but the problem persists

(1) If you're writing kernel code, then learn to use the kernel coding style. (2) Which kernel version are you using? (3) Functions such as gpio_request() return an integer return code that, when negative, indicates the error, aka errno. So instead of merely checking for non-zero, your code needs to store the return code and properly deal with it, such as report it. Note that not every negative return code is fatal. For example an -EPROBE_DEFER means to try again later. (4) Learn to use existing kernel code as examples.

My kernel version is: 6.6.28+rpt-rpi-2712 and im getting an error "insmod: ERROR: could not insert module gpio_driver.ko: Unknown error 517" after using error handling

cross posted at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/147918/not-able-to-access-gpio-pins-on-my-pi5

517 is deferred probe error code, which in case of GPIO means that you asked for not-yet-registered / non-existing GPIO line. Partially you issue is due to usage of legacy APIs, you should use those that starts with gpiod_*(). When you switch to them you will understand better what’s going on.

if your kernel version is higher than 6.6, you can't request GPIO pin with traditional pin number. The base gpio number is no longer pinned as doing so is deprecated in the kernel.
check the correct number of the required GPIO pin in /sys/kernel/debug/gpio

Assuming you have kernel version higher 6.6 and higher, gpio pins are numbered differently. Instead of value 4 for GPIO PIN 4 use 516, for GPIO PIN 17 use 529. All gpio pin numbers can be found in /sys/kernel/debug/gpio

Thanks that helped, but where can i learn more about these changes and the reason behind them?
